# Save selected curves in Graph and dope Editors?

Tags: graph-editor

Is there a way to save a selection of channels in the Graph and Dope editors?

I have tried making keying sets, but you have to make a new key to display the relevant curves, as far as I can see. And you can't get rid of the hierarchical view, which gets cluttered when you have lots of objects. It would be great if you could filter just the channels you want displayed, save the set, and be able to call that set up when needed. (For all its problems, Lightwave worked well in this regard.)

Thanks!